# How to implement DBHelper upgrade method for SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a Content Provider that is backed by a SQLite database. Say I need to add a new column called goodTimes to the database. Say further that I cannot simply do

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Dog.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

as my user may have tasks in progress. So how do I upgrade the database? I also cannot simply not implement `onUpgrade` as I would end up with a SQLiteException when I try to query concerning `goodTimes`. So how do I implement `onUpgrade`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ALTER table statement.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN column-definition
```

This will add the column if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Awesome! can I do ADD COLUMN and REMOVE COLUMN in one query? Or must it be two separate calls to execSQL? (I must wait to accept in 5mins)

Comment: SQLite supports a subset of ALTER TABLE-  you can add new columns but can't drop old ones.  You either need to ignore the old column (and waste space) or you need to create a new table without that column, copy all the data to the new table, drop the old table, then rename the new table to the old table's name.  Yeah, its a pain.